# Exposed local m2 artifacts from a servlet

Tags: maven, servlets, jakarta-ee, repository

Is there a java library that will help in serving the local m2 artifacts under a specific endpoint servlet?

For example: /maven.

Note: I'm familiar with Artifactory and such, but this is not the setup I am looking for.

It's more like I have a project and I want that project to expose the jars in the machine where that project is running.

Comment: Are you trying to construct your own Maven repository?

Comment: Hi @JFMeier, not really but rather use the already existing one. I just need to expose those artifacts in my web project. It's more like I wanted to convert my project into a maven repository. Hopefully, that's clear. Thanks :-)

Comment: Use a repository manager to provide jar's for a Maven/Gradle project...not self crafted solutions...

Comment: @czetsuya This seems like a job for Nexus or Artifactory. Could you explain why you are not looking for this?

Comment: @JFMeier. It's actually a feature of the application that we are building, to serve the jars saved in the local m2, as dynamic classes can be created in the application at run time. For now, if possible we don't want to bundle any repository manager to the app.

Comment: @khmarbaise I would love to do that. But I would not be asking here if that were the case :-)

Answer (score 1):

Working with files is always tricky, you can easily expose data from other directories which can be used by attacker.

To your question: As khmarbaise wrote I'd also really recommend to use Nexus / Artifactory. But if you just need to expose your local repository "the easy way" and "the safe way", you can use web server like Apache2 or Nginx and serve your artifacts as static files.

Lastly if you really want to go to the "danger zone", it's pretty easy to write a Servlet which returns file in some directory, you would call it for example like this: http://localhost:8080/FileServlet?file=junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar And then use this rewrite filter: https://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/ to change URL for example to: http://localhost:8080/repo/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar